# How to get divs to be the same width in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this JQuery to get a div to be the same width as another when the window width is less than 1200px and can't figure out what mistake I'm making.

```
var width = $('.creative').outerWidth();

if ($(window).width() < 1200){

    $('#right-child').css('width', width);
}else{
    console.log('more than 1200');
};
```

Comment: if you're trying to modify the _height_ of a div, then setting the `width` is probably the wrong way to go about it

Comment: `$(window).width()` only gives you the number. You have to append the units to the end of it like in @slick 's example

Comment: you can also try using [CSS3 Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: jQuery's `css()` does in most cases add the appropriate units automagically.

Comment: @Hamms thanks, actually meant width. Just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I  know whats the problem, your code is right! but... If you test these code with the width of the browser in full, nothing will change. You need to add **.resize** event (https://api.jquery.com/resize/), just that!

```
$(window).resize(function(){

        console.log('resize!');
        var width = $('.creative').outerWidth();
        if ($(window).width() < 1200){
            $('#right-child').css('width', width);
        }else{
            console.log('more than 1200');
        };

    });
```

If the problem persist, just let me know.

Answer (score 6):

Try to concatenate the value with unit name.

`$('#right-child').css('width', width + 'px');`

Comment: @EliJayson, I'm not a magician. I cannot guess. Any errors in the console? Try to `console.log()` every line to see where it breaks... Debug your own code.

Comment: just got back to look at this again. Turns out you are a magician and it did actually work. In fact, my initial code actually works too. There were no errors and everything I logged to the console came through so it took me a while to figure this out. I have css flexbox applied to the divs I want to have keep the same width. As flexbox is only supported on certain browsers I added jQuerys as fall backs. For some reason flexbox goes awol between 1200 and ~400px. It doesn't work at all but still somehow overrides the jQuery too. Still working on the solution. Thanks